# Mixed up with rspec assigns while testing controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, controller, assign

I'm trying to get a handle on testing controllers, and so far I seem to be stuck on the simplest problems.

documents.controller:

```
    def edit
      @document = Document.find(params[:id])
    end
```

documents_controller_spec:

```
    describe 'GET #edit', focus: true do
      before(:each) { @doc = FactoryGirl.create(:document)}

      it "should assign @document to the document" do
        get :edit, id: @doc
        assigns(:document).should eq(@doc)
      end
    end
```

Always returns false. @document is always assigned nil. I've tried specifying params[id] to be @doc.id, but that doesn't fix anything. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From rspec's perspective, the two documents (assigned to @doc) you are comparing in the line:

```
assigns(:document).should eq(@doc)
```

are not the same - they have the same ID in the database, but the actual ruby objects you are comparing are different, as one was created in your 'before' block, while the other is presumably instantiated inside your controller when the GET request executes in your test.

My guess is the following will work:

```
assigns(:document).id.should eq(@doc.id)
```

Comment: Oooooooh! That makes a whole lot of sense! I completely forgot about that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```rb
get :edit, id: @doc
```

to

```rb
get :edit, id: @doc.id
```

Basically, it just needs the id to build the route.